# Create List With Numbers Getting Greater Each Time Python

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

How can I make a function that will create a list, increasing the amount of numbers it contains each time to a specified value?

For example if the max was 4, the list would contain

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

It's difficult to explain what I'm looking for, but from the example I think you'll understand!

Thanks

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Well you have to keep track of the number of calls to this function. You can either do that with a global variable, or a static variable that you pass in the function and increment after calling it each time.

Comment: do you want `f(2) -> [1, 2, 2]`?

Comment: I did not understand the question actually))

Comment: ...With no examples tried, I feel like we just did the OP's homework...

Comment: @Izkata if you look at OP's history on the site you may think otherwise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A Nested loop.
This would be a very basic way to do it.
There are much better ways, this should give you the general idea.

```
>>> def listmaker(num):
    l = []
    for i in xrange(1, num+1):
        for j in xrange(i):
            l.append(i)
    return l

>>> print listmaker(4)
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Here is doing it with list comprehension:

```
>>> def listmaker2(num):
    return [y for z in [[x]*(x) for x in xrange(1, num+1)] for y in z]

>>> print listmaker2(4)
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Using extend as suggested.

```
>>> def listmaker3(num):
    l = []
    for i in xrange(1, num+1):
        l.extend([i]*(i))
    return l

>>> print listmaker3(4)
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: why not using "extend"? it should reduce the complexity if final data doesn't need to be sorted

Comment: @luke14free i dont understand where exactly in my code you would want me to do that. a different solution could use extend, maybe i'll write one.

Comment: @luke14free -- There's nothing in the problem statement to imply that the final data doesn't need to be sorted though.  Granted, you could do `l.extend([i]*i)` with `for i in xrange(1,num+1)` as the outer loop.

Comment: @mgilson thanks for reminding me i can set `xrange` to start at 1. gonna edit.

Comment: agreed! i guess the OP wanted a sorted solution.

Comment: The problem with this is that it requires the list be completely generated in advance; a generator expression or iterator function would be preferable, as there is nothing inherently better about storing everything in advance here.

Comment: @InbarRose -- You could add that to your original answer as well to avoid an unnecessary null loop.

Comment: @PhilH im not sure which solution you are referring to. but the OP was no clear on the use, only the desired look. a generator would be simple to produce, but as the OP already marked my answer as accepted, it seems it answers his question. i might add a generator answer just for fun. :)

Comment: @mgilson yeah thanks, missed it in the edit.

Answer (score 17):

I'd use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
itertools.chain(*([i] * i for i in range(1, 5)))
```

or [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to do it slightly more lazily:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable([i] * i for i in range(1, 5))
```

---

And for the ultimate laziness, pair with [`itertools.repeat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) -- (using `xrange` in you're using python2.x):

```
import itertools as it
it.chain.from_iterable(it.repeat(i, i) for i in range(1, 5))
```

As a function:

```
def lazy_funny_iter(n):
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.repeat(i, i) for i in range(1, n+1))

def lazy_funny_list(n):
    return list(lazy_funny_iter(n))
```

Comment: +1  Depending on what the asker wants, you could also replace the range with `itertools.count()` since you're doing everything lazily.

Comment: @NeilG -- Thanks for the upvote.  `count` seems like it would be tricky to use here.  My impression is that it counts indefinitely -- which would make it pretty hard to chain with other things.  `xrange` is lazy in py2k, and `range` is lazy in py3k, so there really shouldn't be a problem with getting a lazy range-like function.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking that if the consumer of the sequence is zipping it with a finite sequence then counting indefinitely saves the caller having to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a recursive function:

```
def my_func(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return []
    else:
        return my_func(x-1) + [x] * x

>>> my_func(4)
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
In [1]: def funny_list(n):
   ...:     return sum(([i]*i for i in range(1, n+1)), [])
   ...: 

In [2]: funny_list(4)
Out[2]: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

This can't be turned into a real generator, though, unlike `itertools.chain`, which is the canonical way to go.

Comment: Interesting use of `sum`

Comment: One thing to beware of when using `sum` this way is that it will show quadratic behaviour, and so if `n` is (say) 100 it'll take hundreds of times longer than `itertools.chain`.  Often that doesn't matter, of course.

Comment: @DSM Ah. Yes. sum each array :)

Answer (score 4):

Different perspective to the problem (a bit less complex):

```
>>> a = range(1,5)
>>> for i in range(2,5):
...     a.extend(range(i,5))
... 
>>> print sorted(a) #Remove the sort if you don't need it
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

A fairly direct way of creating a list as shown is via

```
[i for i in range(1,n+1) for j in range(i)]
```

where `n` is the largest number to appear in the list.  The above is equivalent to the methods used in several previously suggested answers, but slightly cleaner in expression.

An alternative to all the methods mentioned so far is to note that the `i`th element of the list is approximately equal to the integer part of the square root of `2*i`.  With slight adjustments, this makes a fairly simple generator possible, as follows.

```
def gen_nnlist(nmax):
    n = 1
    while n < nmax*(nmax+1):
        yield int(n**.5+.5)
        n += 2
```

Here is some sample output from exercising the code in the python 2.7.3 interpreter:

```
>>> print [i for i in gen_nnlist(4)]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>> print [i for i in gen_nnlist(6)]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
>>> fun = gen_nnlist(3)
>>> for i in fun: print i
... 
1
2
2
3
3
3
>>>
```

Comment: +1 for the cleanest answer here.  surprisingly, I had no idea that list comps could be nested in a flat way like this.  That's kind of cool, although I'm sure I'll forget which loop is inside and which loop is outside ...

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> list(''.join([str(x) * x for x in range(1, 5)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a generator:

```
>>> def growingSeq(maxN):
...     for n in range(1,maxN+1):
...         for _ in range(n):
...             yield n
... 
>>> growingSeq(4)
<generator object growingSeq at 0x1004db280>
>>> list(growingSeq(4))
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: if we really want generator, go full speed with syntax `xrange` rather than `range`.

Comment: In most actual use cases, the ease of typing and reading `range` instead of `xrange` will save more time than the runtime difference between the two. Plus Python 3.